# Is it possible to make the app settings editable by using reflection to adjust the readonly attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, app-config

I found the following code to set the readonly attribute to false for the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` property:

```
    typeof(ConfigurationElementCollection)
        .GetField("bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .SetValue(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings, false);
```

Is it possible to apply this to make the `AppSettings` property also editable?

AppSettings is a `NameValueCollection` which implements `NameObjectCollectionBase` which has the `IsReadOnly` property on it. However if I call `GetFields()` it returns an empty list.

Edit:

What I am trying to do is modify my appsettings in a unit test, then execute a method that will read from app settings and perform some functions.

So any option that allows me to change the appsettings in memory (but not persist them to disk) would work. Ideally, without recycling the app pool.

It works for connection strings, but I am unable to get app settings to be editable using the same technique.

Comment: Are you trying to edit configurations in `AppSettings` section?

Comment: Can you please add the code that you are working with ( which returns the empty list ).

Comment: Can you take a moment to explain what you're actually trying to achieve here rather than how you're trying to do it pls.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @SLC Why not make an interface for fetching such app settings and swapping out for a mocked implementation in your tests? The mocked implementation needn't look at appsettings at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update a setting in `AppSettings` section of your `*.config` file and then persist it, the the code below should do the trick.

```
private void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    var configuration = ConfigurationManager
       .OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

    // Now we need to update the setting in memory as well
    UpdateSettingInMemory(key, value);
}

private void UpdateSettingInMemory(string key, string value)
{
    var configuration = ConfigurationManager
        .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Comment: MSDN says the save method `Writes the configuration settings contained within this Configuration object to the current XML configuration file`. I don't want to persist anything to disk though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/nameobjectcollectionbase.cs,e9b54a57aee818b9) the underlying field is named `_readOnly`, so with the right `BindingFlags` there should be no problem to get this fields an change its value.

Alternatively you could get the `IsReadOnly` property and change its value by calling the setter method or using the `SetValue` shortcut.

Comment: Thanks - I've set _readOnly to false, and verified it using intellisense on the appsettings object, but I still get the same error when I add a setting that it is readonly. Could it be a readonly setting on a different object?

Comment: Maybe; if this is the case you should be able to find it using the debugger. I dont have access to machine to debug it by myself at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: There is a field called _root of type `AppSettingSection` which has a _bReadyOnly value set to false. I am trying to work out how to change this.

Comment: Can you add the full code, what you really want to do to, to your question? I am not familiar with the `AppSettings` and don't know how you would use them.